# Adjust fieldset according to inner table

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8, fieldset

I have this code:

```
<fieldset>
 <label>show/hide table</label>
  <table class="tableStyle2">
    table code - a wide table
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

The fieldset auto adjust it's width in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8. Is there A fix for this?
Tried:

```
.tableStyle2 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode','Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif';
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `disply:inline-block` to `fieldset`

```
fieldset{width:auto; display:inline-block}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vqjYu/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Did you try applying the width style directly to the fieldset properties?

```
<fieldset style="width: 100%;">...</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks man. That `"width=auto;"` didn't work for me. This works beautifully.